# Hello please i have difficulties in setting up my Github account

Tags: github-pages

I successfully created my GitHub account and also my Repository and when I navigate to the settle, I can't find GitHub pages that say launch an automatic [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzR4M.jpg)website. please I've been stuck here for days and do not know what else to do.

I expect to find GitHub pages when I navigate to settle. but when I navigate to settle I can not find the option that[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6FE4.jpg) says Launch an automatic page generator